# Django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 error with google

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, google-oauth

I am using Django 1.11 with Django Rest Framework 3.6. I am trying to schedule a social network login from an Android application with the django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 plugin but I am having an error that is not solved.

### Configuration setting.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth',
'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookAppOAuth2',
# 'social_core.backends.instagram.InstagramOAuth2',
'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',
'frontend.login.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = ****
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = ***

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
...
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
...
'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
)
}
```

The data configuration according to the documents.

Then from Postman I make the next call and it returns an error 400.

enter the description of the image here
[image]
The fact is that it returns the error:

> The backend responded with HTTP403: the daily limit for
>   unauthenticated use was exceeded. Continuous use requires
>   registration.

Comment: did you got solutions ?

Comment: No, I had to remove the plugin and perform the social login with this other plugin https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: Can you share the code of Google sign in DRF , I spent one week no proper example